# Does this way need to use the close in python?

Tags: python

```
data = [json.loads(line) for line in open('music.json', 'r')]
```

In this way, do I need to close the file somehow? It doesn't have a handle to close it.

Is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

The standard/idiomatic way to do something like this is to wrap it inside a `with` block. This would make your line look something like this:

```py
with open('music.json', 'r') as music:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in music]
```

The `with` block takes a closable object (a file in this case) and a variable. It assigns the variable to the object for the duration of the block of code, and when the block finishes, it automatically closes the object. For more information, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement.